# query in mongo Shell gives SyntaxError: missing : after property

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-shell

```
db.movieDetails.find(
  { year: 2013, imdb.rating: Pg-13, award.wins: 0 },
  { title: 1, _id: 0 }
).pretty();
```

The mongo shell returns this error

> 2016-08-13T09:08:00.648+0200 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: missing
>   : after property id @(shell):1:60

Why?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If your query includes inner documents, then use quotes for them. Also, use quotes for querying String values

```
db.movieDetails.find(
  { year: 2013, "imdb.rating": "Pg-13", "award.wins": 0 },
  { title: 1, _id: 0 }
).pretty();
```

Comment: This can also happen if an operator is expection a single argument but you have put it in curly braces. For example `{$sqrt: {$_id}}` is incorrect since it should be `{$sqrt: "$_id"}`.

Comment: I get the same error running the following command: `rocky26 = Movie.create({:title  "Rocky XXVI"})` doesn't mongo generate the ID automatically?

Comment: same error was coming to me at the time of INSERT, fixed it similar way, by adding quotes over inner documents (y)

Answer (score 8):

This error also comes if  **":" is missed.**

In my case **I missed the **":"** after $set** like the below.

**db.myData.updateOne({_id:ObjectId("new_id")},{$set{name:"new_name"}})**

I faced the same error mentioned in the title and my changed code that works is

**db.myData.updateOne({_id:ObjectId("new_id")},{$set:{name:"new_name"}})**

Hope this helps people who did my mistake.